# Split string with nested dictionary and convert into Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I've this issue with this data.

First Lines of CSV

```
{'grade1': '47.614465', 'grade2': '-122.32174', 'grade3': '{"addr": "123 AV MOUNTIAN", "town": "HAMBOURG", "dep": GR", "code": ""}'}
{'grade1': '47.61699416', 'grade2': '-122.320405', 'grade3': '{"addr": "5555 WALL STREET", "town": "NY", "dep": "NY", "code": "98122"}'}
{'grade1': '47.61676902', 'grade2': '-122.3215492', 'grade3': '{"addr": "6776  SPAU - 65 ", "town": "GHAN", "dep": "IU", "code": "122"}'}
```

After import my csv file I get this dataframe:

```
Grade
0   {'grade1': '47.614465', 'grade2': '-122.32174', 'grade3': '{"addr": "123 AV MOUNTIAN", "town": "HAMBOURG", "dep": GR", "code": ""}'}
1   {'grade1': '47.61699416', 'grade2': '-122.320405', 'grade3': '{"addr": "5555 WALL STREET", "town": "NY", "dep": "NY", "code": "98122"}'}
2   {'grade1': '47.61676902', 'grade2': '-122.3215492', 'grade3': '{"addr": "6776 SPAU - 65 ", "town": "GHAN", "dep": "IU", "code": "122"}'}
```

There's only one column and the data type is an object

I need to convert this into a dataframe and get this output

```
  grade1        grade2         addr              town         dep       code
47.614465     -122.32174    123 AV MOUNTIAN    HAMBOURG       GR            
47.61699416   -122.320405   5555 WALL STREET      NY          NY        98122
```

I've tried following code :

```
dic_loc=[]
#adress=[]
cordinates=[]
address=[]
for key, value in df['grade'][:3].items():  
    print (key,value, type(value), pd.Series(value), type(pd.Series(value)))
    dic_loc.append(value)  ### I get a string
```

The result is :

```
{'grade1': '47.614465', 'grade2': '-122.32174', 'grade3': '{"addr": "123 AV MOUNTIAN", "town": "HAMBOURG", "dep": GR", "code": ""}'} <class 'str'> 0
```

The issue is how iterate over this string and convert it into a DataFrame?

Any ideas are welcome 
Help really appreciated

Comment: Was your csv originally a json file? It would be easier to use that to import.

Comment: You should fix how you import the data.

Comment: The csv was not a json file

Comment: #Barmar - You mean ?

Comment: Could you paste the first lines of your CSV into your question?

Comment: Your file isn't a CSV. It is a sequnce of JSON strings, one per line.

Comment: It's a CSV file, and the column grade content is in this format

Comment: @Błotosmętek is right, that's nowhere near valid, or sensible, CSV. Why is part of the data, like `'{"addr": "123 AV MOUNTIAN", "town": "HAMBOURG", "dep": GR", "code": ""}'`, a string, instead of the same structure as the rest.

Comment: Well, I was **part** right  - this is neither valid CSV nor valid JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it can be fixed the following way:

```
import json, pandas

def fix_line(line):
    # first convert the string to proper JSON
    json_string = line.replace("'",'"').replace('"{', '{').replace('}"', '}')
    # convert JSON to dict
    d = json.loads(json_string)
    # convert dict to a tuple 
    return (float(d['grade1']), float(d['grade2']), d['grade3']['addr'],
        d['grade3']['town'], d['grade3']['dep'], d['grade3']['code'])

# create a dataframe from a list of tuples
df = pandas.DataFrame.from_records([fix_line(line) for line in df['Grade']], 
     columns=['grade1', 'grade2', 'addr', 'town', 'dep', 'code'])

print(df)
```

Comment: Great job. I've also found something similar at this link, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57064198/trying-to-extract-one-column-that-seems-to-be-json-from-a-pandas-dataframe-in-py  hoping this can help.